# Размер резервируемых данных в памяти

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Добрый день, возникла проблема с использованием памяти приложением, когда происходит передача файла (2 Мб) на сервер. Размер приложения в памяти из 102 Мб превращается в 1.2 Гб, что, собственно, проблема. Не могу понять почему не происходит очистка ресурсов.

**Здесь создается класс контракта данных**

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Name = "ExecFile")]
[KnownType(typeof(System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher))]
public class ExecFile  // класс c файлом 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "File")]
    public byte[] File = new byte[40000000];
    [DataMember(Name = "FileName")]
    public string FileName = "";
}
```

**Только здесь он используется**

```
   public void SendDataSettingPC(string ParameterType, string ParameterRequest, int PositionData) // Выполняет комманды сервера
    {
        string Result = "";
        string FileName = "";
        lock (ValueWCFRequest.MainChannelSending)
        {
            if (ParameterRequest != "" && File.Exists(ParameterRequest))
            {
                ValueWCFRequest.MainAddressEndepont = new EndpointAddress("http://" + ValueWCFConnect.WCFServer_IP + ":" + ValueWCFConnect.WCFServer_Port + "/AdministrationServiceManagement/MainEndpoint");
                ValueWCFRequest.MainChannelSending = new ChannelFactory<IWCFService>(ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol, ValueWCFRequest.MainAddressEndepont);
                try
                {
                    IWCFService WCFClientOpen = ValueWCFRequest.MainChannelSending.CreateChannel();
                    using (FileStream CreatArray = new FileStream(ParameterRequest, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        ExecFile SetData = new ExecFile();
                        XmlSerializer XmlData = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExecFile));
                        byte[] DataFile = new byte[40000000];
                        int Leng = (int)CreatArray.Length;
                        int CountCell;
                        int SumCell = 0;
                        while ((CountCell = CreatArray.Read(DataFile, SumCell, Leng - SumCell)) > 0)
                        {
                            SumCell += CountCell;  // опеределяем необходимое количество строк в байтовом массиве путем смещения 
                        }
                        CreatArray.Close();
                        CreatArray.Dispose();
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(ParameterRequest);
                        SetData.FileName = FileName;
                        Array.Copy(DataFile, SetData.File, SumCell);
                        using (StringWriter Stream = new StringWriter())
                        {
                            XmlData.Serialize(Stream, SetData);
                            Result = WCFClientOpen.MainMethodsInternal(ParameterType, Stream.ToString());
                        }
                        Array.Clear(SetData.File, 0, SetData.File.Length);
                    }
                    ValueWCFRequest.MainChannelSending.Close();
                    GC.Collect();
                }
                catch (Exception Error)
                {
                    SettingPC.BasicMethods.ValueSetting.TypeSourceData = "localhost";
                    MessageBox.Show("Не удалось связаться с сервером " + Error.Message, "Ошибка cоединения", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
            else return;
        }
```

Использовал сборщик мусора. Да, он помогает, но с 1.2 Гб до 412 Мб, что всё равно многовато. Да и почему он вообще резервирует такой объем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вижу, что Вы используете WCF сервис. А значит доступна поточная отдача результатов запроса. То есть не нужно формировать весь ответ в памяти и отдавать одним куском, можно выделить буфер, хоть на 30 КБайт и отдавать такими порциями.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Сейчас Вы задали очень большой буфер 40 000 000 - около 40 МБайт, выделяете этот буфер дважды. То есть уже 80 МБайт. После сериализации в XML (сомнительной нужности) класса размером в 40 МБайт, получите XML-ку на 1,33 * 40 = 52 МБайт чистых данных + обвес. Когда это будет превращаться в строку, то выделится ещё буфер на 50+ МБайт. Строка в 50 МБайт начнет превращаться в ответ сервера, начнёт кодироваться в нужную кодировку и ещё 100+ МБайт. На ровном месте 300+ МБайт занято.

Отдавать файлы с сервера по запросу клиента без какой либо проверки имени и прав доступа - нехорошо.

Comment: Проверка регистрационных данных происходит в отдельном классе, с этим нет проблем, но он изначально у меня 1,2 Гб занимает, без сборщика мусора и почиму он не диспозит эти обьекты если есть блок using

Comment: @SergD29 1) момент сборки мусора недетерминирован, 2) `Dispose()` не занимается освобождением памяти.

Comment: @SergD29 using гарантирует, что не будет утечки ресурсов. Что если клиент принимающий ответ закроет соединение или другая нештатная ситуация случится - поток закроется. Но пока клиент читает ответ сервера, сервер будет держать ответ в памяти. А клиент может считывать ответ размером в 50+ МБайт минуту или две. Если клиентов несколько, то они исчерпают ресурсы сервера.

Comment: @SergD29 под проверкой имени и прав доступа имел в виду проверку имени файла, проверку прав доступа пользователя на файл. Если пользователь пришлёт запрос на чтение файла web.config или файла с базой данных - защиты от такого в коде не видно.